# Ionic 2 - building grid

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, grid

I was searching for informations about IONIC 2 grid but I didn't find complex description of it. I've got some questions:

1. Can I include one `<ion-grid>` inside another `<ion-grid>`?
2. If I have some modules can I build grid for every module separately?
3. If not maybe I should declare `<ion-grid>` higher in DOM than modules and in modules operate only on `<ion row>` and `<ion-col>`
4. I find something like that:

   `<div class="row"><div class="col-6"></div><div class="col-6"></div>
   </div>`

Is that IONIC (maybe the old one)?
In IONIC2 it should look like:

```
<ion-row">
<ion-col col-6"></ion-col>
<ion-col col-6"></ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Am I right?

PS. Thats my first post on stackoverflow :D Jupi!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Can I include one  inside another ?**

Yes you can, but I haven't seen a use case where this was required.

**If I have some modules can I build grid for every module separately?**

Yes you can, you should see `<ion-grid>` the same as any other Ionic component like `<ion-item>` or `<ion-card>`. Use them as much as you need them in any module.

**I find something like that:**

```
<div class="row"><div class="col-6"></div><div class="col-6"></div>
</div>
```

This is the old version of the , proper use and more information  about the `<ion-grid>` component can be found [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/)

Comment: Thanks! You helped me a lot :D

Comment: If my answer was helpfull to you, please consider accepting this answer.

Comment: "Can I include one inside another? Yes you can, but I haven't seen a use case where this was required." - what about this situation - I have main app with a lot of modules in it. Main app has its own <ion-grid> tag and every module has own <ion-grid> tags.

Comment: Every page could have it's own <ion-grid>, or even multiple. This shouldn't be any problem.